# RecyclerView with Adapter does not keep values stored in Android

Tags: android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have the following simple recyclerview layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SurvivorPicksheetActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This recycler view links to the detailed layout of the list items as such:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/rootView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/gamefield_background" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/away"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|left"/>


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/home"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:scaleX="-1"/>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Inside my Adapter java class I have an setOnClickListener for the two ImageView items.

If a user clicks on them the item is selected while the old item is unselected.

The problem I am encountering if that lets say the list of items has 25 items. If I click on the lets say 3rd item, everything works as expected.

Then I scroll to the end of the list, and scroll back up to the top, the selection is not longer valid even thought I clicked/selected prior to scrolling to the end of the list.

I can reclick and item at the top, scroll down and scroll back up and my selection is gone!?

Does anyone know why this is happening and more importantly how i can resolve it!?

### UPDATE:

The following is my Adapter class:

```
public class GameAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<GameAdapter.GameViewHolder> {

    // variable that holds the selected team
    private String selectedTeam = "";

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(GameViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Games game = gameList.get(position);

        holder.awayTeamImageView.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            if (selectedTeam.equals(String.valueOf(game.getHomeId()))) {

                // RESET PLAYER SELECTION
                selectedTeam = "";
                selectedGame = "";

            } else {

                // SET PLAYER SELECTION
                selectedTeam = String.valueOf(game.getHomeId());
                selectedGame = String.valueOf(game.getKey());

            }

        }

    }

}

class GameViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
 
    public GameViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        
        awayImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.away);

        homeImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.home);


        homeImageView.setOnClickListener(this);

        awayImageView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

}
```

Based on my code above, I 'think' I am setting and unsetting the selected team so that when I scroll to the end and back to the top the selected team should remain vs being recycled and not displaying anymore?!

Answer (score 0):

That's because the old `Views` are being recycled, back to the initial state. And this is a natutral behavior of `RecyclerView`.

In order to make each item `View` "memorize" its check/select state, you need to create a field in your model class to record the state, like `isChecked` or `isSelected`.

Comment: can you please elaborate, or show a sample, I am new to Android and am mainly an ios dev, so this is really new to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use own domain ViewHolder and ViewModel for recycleview.

Android developer documents gives basic understanding of how to create dynamic  RecycleView in below link.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

This is expected as the views are recycled and lose their values accordingly whenever you scroll up/down the list; further for configuration changes (like screen rotation) the selected views will be lost.

To fix this, you should go for [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) to have persistent data even for configuration changes.

But, as a rescuer, assuming the adapter provided list of games `gameList` is in a persistent storage like mentioned above; then you can:

- Create a selection boolean in the `Games` model class with getter/setter which has a false initially.
- When a row is selected from the `RecyclerView`, then set the boolean to true like `gameList.get(selectedPosition).setIsSelected(true)`
- Then `notifyItemChanged()` of that position.